# Inequality for $d(A,B)=\inf\{\varepsilon>0:B\subset(1+\varepsilon)A\}$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, analysis, convex-analysis

> Suppose that $A,B,C,D$ are convex sets containing the origin and $A\subset B$ and $C\subset D$.
>   Define
>   $$
> d(A,B)=\inf\{\varepsilon>0:B\subset(1+\varepsilon)A\}.
> $$
>   I am trying to show that
>   $$
> d(A\cap C,B\cap D)\le\max\{d(A,B),d(C,D)\}.
> $$

We have that
$$
d(A\cap C,B\cap D)=\inf\{\varepsilon>0:B\cap D\subset(1+\varepsilon)(A\cap C)\}.
$$
Since $B\cap D\subset B$ and $A\cap C\subset A$, we cannot say anything about 
$$
d(A\cap B)=\inf\{\varepsilon>0:B\subset(1+\varepsilon)A\}
$$
(it can be larger, smaller or equal depending on how much $B$ is bigger than $B\cap D$ and how much bigger is $A$ than $A\cap C$).  However, we should be able to conclude that the largest of $d(A\cap B)$ and $d(C\cap D)$ cannot be smaller than $d(A\cap C,B\cap D)$, but I just cannot find a contradiction or an argument to show that.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is $(1+\varepsilon)A$ the set of point with distance smaller $\varepsilon$ from $A$?

Comment: @1524 Intuitively, for $\varepsilon>0$ and $A\subset\mathbb R^n$, $(1+\varepsilon)A$ denotes the set that we obtain by multiplying each element of $A$ by $(1+\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we call $d(A,B)=\varepsilon_1$, $d(C,D)=\varepsilon_2$, then $B\subset (1+\varepsilon_1+\delta)A$, $D\subset (1+\varepsilon_2+\delta)C,\forall \delta >0$ and $$B\cap D\subset (1+\varepsilon_1+\delta)A\cap (1+\varepsilon_2+\delta)C\subset (1+\max\{\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2\}+\delta)(A\cap C),$$ thus $d(A\cap C,B\cap D)\leq \max\{\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2\}+\delta$ for all $\delta>0$, then $d(A\cap C,B\cap D)\leq \max\{\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2\}$.

Comment: I think I'm missing something...

Comment: Thanks (+1), I think this works! Somehow I missed that... We just have to be careful with the infimum. $B$ is not necessarily a subset of $(1+d(A,B))A$, but it is a subset of $(1+d(A,B)+\delta)A$ for each $\delta>0$.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. Corrected. Fortunately the conclusion remains the same even when we sum $\delta$'s along the way haha. But I still feel uncomfortable about the fact we didn't use convexity...

Comment: We need convexity to show that $aA\cap bB\subset\max\{a,b\}(A\cap B)$ for any $a>0$ and $b>0$, right?

Comment: Yes and we also need the hypothesis you wrote about the origin, because if $x\in A$ and $a<b$ then $ax$ is in the line connecting $bx$ and $0$ and then, in $bA$. Thank you, now I'm comfortable with my answer.